# Android NsdManager periodically lost+found avahi daemon service

Tags: android, networking, daemon, avahi, nsd

I have linux PC with installed avahi-daemon (default config) and registered service test.local.
From iOS discovering test.local service thru Bonjour works like a charm but from Android not.
Nsd Manager periodically (every second) call NsdManager.DiscoveryListener OnSeviceLost() and right after that OnServiceFound().
Actual discovering works but every second OnServiceLost occur and it's broke my internal software logic.

My Andoid code based on following document:
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Is there some special configuration for "avahi daemon"/Android to prevent described behavior (periodically Lost+Found service discovering) ?

Comment: Have you got any resolution for this ?

Comment: No ! I have added workaround in my application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the standard behavior, as RxDNSSD is also behaving the same way.